# Long polling and other fallback support for Websocket using Jetty 9

Tags: websocket, jetty, long-polling, fallback

Can somebody please let me know how i can add long polling and other fallback support for websocket using Jetty 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally recommend using something like CometD (http://www.cometd.org) which will be releasing version 3 fairly soon which will support Jetty 9.  Another option would be to look at the Atmosphere project.

Using a messaging framework like these let you have the framework handle finding the best protocol to use, be it SPDY, Websocket, HTTP/1.1 or even polling HTTP/1.0....and they isolate you from future protocols like HTTP/2 which is coming (slowly) which is based on spdy.  Using CometD once that protocol lands and becomes available get it for free, no changes needed in your app.

Comment: Thanks @jesse mcconnell for the suggestion... More specifically, can i be able to use web-socket-js (https://github.com/simb/web-socket-js) with Jetty as the server side technology and still be able to transparently support long polling and other fallback support in cases where websocket support isn't available?